# Como compilar codigo C++ com interface separada? (arq.h , arq.cpp e main.cpp)

Tags: c, c++

Estou estudando C++ pelo livro da Deitel e estou tentando compilar um programa onde temos um arquivo gradebook.h que é a interface, gradebook.cpp que é a implementação e main.cpp. Sempre que rodo o programa ele me retorna erros de referencia indefinida. Já executei uma dica de um colega daqui em outro post (g++ -o gradebook gradebook.cpp main.cpp), nesse caso não me retorna mais os erros, entretanto, também não me retorna nada no terminal. simplesmente compila e finaliza. Segue o codigo:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gradebook.h" // definição de classe GradeBook
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //cria dois objetos GradeBook
    GradeBook gradeBook1( "CS101 Introduction to Programming in C++" );
    GradeBook gradeBook2( "CS102 Data Structures in C++ ");

    //exibe courseName de cada GradeBook
    cout << "gradeBook1's initial course name is: " << gradeBook1.getCourseName()
         << "\ngradeBook2's initial course name is: " << gradeBook2.getCourseName() << endl;

    //modifica courseName do myGradeBook (com uma string de comprimento valido)
    gradeBook1.setCourseName( "CS101 C++ Programming");

    //Exibe valor inicial de courseName para cada GradeBook
    cout << "\ngradeBook1's course name is: " << gradeBook1.getCourseName() 
         << "\ngradeBook2's course name is: " << gradeBook2.getCourseName()
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gradebook.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gradebook.h" //Definição de classe GradeBook
using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook( string name )
{
    setCourseName( name );
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName( string name )
{
    if ( name.length() <= 25 )
    {
        courseName = name;
    }
    
    if ( name.length() > 25 )
    {
        courseName = name.substr( 0, 25 );

        cout << "Name \"" << name << "\" exceeds maximum lenght (25). \n"
             << "Limiting courseName to first 25 characters.\n" << endl;
    }
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
}
```

gradebook.h

```
#include <string> // a classe GradeBook utiliza a classe de string padrao C++
using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
    public:
        GradeBook( string ); // Construtor que inicializa courseName
        void setCourseName( string ); //configura o nome do curso
        string getCourseName(); // obtem o nome do curso
        void displayMessage(); // exibe mensagem de boas vindas
    private:
        string courseName; //nome do curso para este GradeBook
};
```

Comment: Vc já tentou executar o arquivo com `./gradebook` no terminal?

Comment: É só executar no terminal como a @aviana disse com `./gradebook` em linux e mac ou `gradebook` apenas em windows. Para complementar você indica os nomes de todos os cpps quando compila com `g++` no terminal e a opção `-o` é para indicar qual o nome do programa gerado.

Comment: Talvez você não tenha entendido o propósito. Compilar o programa pode ser apenas gerar arquivos objeto, aqueles com extensão .OBJ, caso você rode gcc -c gradebook.cpp. Se você rodar gcc -o azul gradebook.cpp main.cpp o resultado vai ser a criação de azul.exe. Só isso. Não vai rodar o programa azul.exe, que se supõe possa ser guardado e executado talvez em outras máquinas. Esse é o objetivo de um programa. Não se espera que ele vá ser compilado a cada vez antes de ser executado. Não se espera que ele seja executado toda vez que for compilado

Comment: Agora sim compreendi. Sou bem iniciante e não havia encontrado uma outra explicação a respeito. Deu certinho aqui!! Muito grato a todos!